# I want to convert String-> { \"Name\":Value } to -> { "Name" : Value } . Can i do it ? and How to do that ? Thanks

Tags: java, android

String str = str.replaceAll("\","");  // Failed

*/  This result i want is format  '\'  all place   /*

Comment: there is no '\' character in the string. It is only there to escape double quotes character next to it. so when you print the string, it will anyway show you without \.

Comment: Try This->  String s =  "{\"Name\":10}";
        String a = s.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

Answer (score 1):

you can you google's json library to properly convert your string's to json. here is the dependency used by me in my maven project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The following code would give you your output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "{\"Name\":10}";
        System.out.println(new Gson().fromJson(a, YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class));
}
```

if you don't have a transfer object ready to keep Object class as your ClassName. This is just to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` is a special character in a regular expression, so you have to escape it :

```
\\
```

BUT, the backslash in a `String` has to be escaped too, so you have to escape each of those two backslashes :

```
\\ + \\ --> \\\\
```

You end up with :

```
String str = str.replaceAll("\\\\","");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this friend

String str = str.replace("\","");

Comment: This wont compile.

Comment: I can see 2 compile errors in this piece of code (double declaration of "str" and not escaping of the backslash), did you check your code before ninja-answering?

Comment: you wrote the same as question